# Why isn't there any continuation to the Planetes' anime?

Tags: planetes

*Planetes* was really well received but yet it doesn't have an anime continuation even though I hear the manga goes well beyond the anime (I think until exploration to Jupiter?).

I can't seem to find any reason why it's not happening, is it because it didn't have enough viewers or is it because it's been too long since the anime last aired? Usually anime that won't get a conclusion has an explicit reason but this one doesn't and it's really bothersome.

Comment: If you aren't aware, the anime is not adaptation direct adaptation of the manga. There are a fair amount of differences in design, story, and characters. It should be considered it's own thing instead of an adaptation of the manga. Each anime production committee has their own idea of what they want to do. There's no real ground rules on what they have to do.

Comment: "Usually anime that won't get a conclusion has an explicit reason" - goodness, no. Not at all. Quite the contrary - I would estimate that at least half of all non-original anime fail to adapt their source material to the end. Incomplete adaptations are by far more typical, at least in recent times.

Comment: I haven't seen Planetes, but just from reading the [MyAnimeList page](https://myanimelist.net/anime/329/Planetes), it sounds like one of those series that's critically acclaimed but a bit too challenging for many audiences. If that's so, it probably didn't actually make all that much money. Just guessing, though.

Comment: Is this considered off-topic due to it being about **unannounced future events with regard to the production of an anime or manga?**

Comment: @ThePickleTickler You could go that way, but in this case I'd favor leaving it open. Given what we know now, you _can_ create a good answer to this question by looking at the sales figures and critical reaction to the first show, similar to questions that ask "What was So-and-so's motive for doing such-and-such in ongoing series XX where we don't know yet but might find out later?" That's different from questions that ask "When is blah blah coming out?", where it's impossible to answer the question at all, let alone well, until blah blah's release date is announced.

Comment: Ah well, thank you all for trying to help. I suppose some anime series, there's just no public explanation but if I were to guess with Torisuda, it would be because seinen has to be massively popular to continue since it doesn't make much money off of merchandise. I also didn't know it differed greatly than the manga, therefore I'll start reading the manga. This anime is close to my heart so I appreciate every comment here. Thank you!